# self join with QUALIFY RANK() OVER PARTITION BY results in spool space error

Tags: sql, teradata

I perform a self join on 2 simplified tables with 2 columns: SomeId and Measure1 (there is a primary index on SomeId). This is the simplified query:

```
SELECT
    One.SomeId AS SomeIdOne
    ,Two.SomeId AS SomeIdTwo
FROM SomeTable AS One
INNER JOIN SomeTable AS Two
ON 
    One.SomeId <> Two.SomeId
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY One.SomeId ORDER BY 
    (One.Measure1 - Two.Measure1) ASC) = 1
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid the spool space error?

PS:

Simplified example:

```
DROP TABLE SomeTable;
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE SomeTable
(
        SomeId INT,
        Measure1 DECIMAL(14,4)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeId, Measure1) VALUES (1, 3.0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeId, Measure1) VALUES (2, 4.0);
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeId, Measure1) VALUES (3, 5.0);
```

Desired result:

```
SomeIdOne   SomeIdTwo   Distance
1   2   1.0000
2   1   1.0000
3   2   2.0000
```

Possible but inefficient query (see question):

```
SELECT
    One.SomeId AS SomeIdOne
    ,Two.SomeId AS SomeIdTwo
    ,ABS(One.Measure1 - Two.Measure1) AS Distance
FROM SomeTable AS One
INNER JOIN SomeTable AS Two
ON 
    One.SomeId <> Two.SomeId
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY One.SomeId ORDER BY 
    (ABS(One.Measure1 - Two.Measure1)) ASC) = 1;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  And explain the logic you want to implement.  There is probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Not sure how to do this in my case as it is sensitive data. However, in a nutshell, I would like to get the closest line based on the numeric variable Measure1.

Comment: Of course this blows your spool, it's almost an unrestricted cross join. The closest line can be only the row directly before or after the current row sorted by Measure1.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks but how can I avoid this?

Comment: Show some example rows and explain the logic the get the expected result.

Comment: @dnoeth - see PS. I hope this makes more sense?

Comment: Are you sure about the result? This returns the ID of the row with the highest Measure1 and the difference between this value and the current row (only the row highest Measure1 is different, but this can be done using a CASE. `SELECT t.*,
   First_Value(SomeId) 
   Over (ORDER BY Measure1 DESC
         ) 
  ,Measure1 - Max(Measure1) Over ()    
FROM SomeTable AS t`

Comment: sorry your sql does not run at my end.

Comment: What's you Teradata release? `FIRST_VALUE` was introduced in TD14.10.

Comment: Def. not 14.10 - its fairly old. Is there a command I can run to find out?

Comment: `SELECT InfoData FROM dbc.dbcinfo
WHERE InfoKey = 'RELEASE'` returns version info. But your query actually implements the correct logic?

Comment: @dnoeth - we will actually upgrade to 14+ soon (-: Anyway I have updated the simplified example. It def. produces the desired results (ignoring the fact that if there are ties it returns 2 rows - not sure how to overcome this). Could you please have a look and suggest a solution pre14.+?

Comment: The tie issue can be resolved by using row_number instead of rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum distance is easy to find when you order the data by measure, it's either to the previous or the next row.

```
SELECT 
   dt.SomeId
  ,CASE 
     WHEN prevDist IS NULL    THEN nextID
     WHEN nextDist IS NULL    THEN prevID
     WHEN prevDist < nextDist THEN prevID
     ELSE nextID
   END
  ,CASE 
     WHEN prevDist IS NULL    THEN nextDist -- first row
     WHEN nextDist IS NULL    THEN prevDist -- last row
     WHEN prevDist < nextDist THEN prevDist -- chose the smaller value
     ELSE nextDist
   END  
FROM 
 (
   SELECT SomeId
     ,Measure1 -
      Min(Measure1) -- previous row
      Over (ORDER BY Measure1 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS prevDist
     ,Min(Measure1) -- next row 
      Over (ORDER BY Measure1 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
      - Measure1                                      AS nextDist
     ,Min(SomeId) -- previous row 
      Over (ORDER BY Measure1 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS prevID
     ,Min(SomeId) -- next row  
      Over (ORDER BY Measure1 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following) AS nextID
   FROM SomeTable AS t
 ) AS dt
```

Regarding ties this currently returns one row randomly, you might add another column to ORDER BY and change the CASE logic to get a specific row with a higher/lower Id.

Btw, granted it's sensitive data, but can you explain the actual business question behind this?

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, the real problem is a bit more complicated. the actually formula to calculate the distance is the MSE: ((One.Measure1 - Two.Measure1)**2 + ... + (One.Measure50 - Two.Measure50)**2)/50 so there are 50 measures. Just kept this simple. The business use case is to identify the closest 'widget' with the most similar 50 measures. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @csetzkorn: It's better when you don't oversimplify, there's no way to get this result without a Product Join. The number of rows in spool before aggregation will be `N * number of AMPs`, calculate that number and multiply times the size of a row. Additionally the OLAP step uses two spools, this double again (hopefully Explain doesn't tell *spool will not be cached in memory*). Now if can convince your DBA to grant you that much spool, you still need `N*(N-1)` calculations done and then that aggregation, at least `PI(SomeIdOne)` should result in *aggregated locally*. Good luck :-)

Comment: Ok fair enough - makes all sense. I will split this up into smaller chunks and run it in batches via SAS.